# Capture output of a command in a bash script that segfaults

Tags: linux, bash

OS: lubuntu 13.04

I am running a simple bash script to save various system information to a file.  I primarily am just echo'ing in output from commands into a file.  One of the commands I run is:

```
echo "$(nmcli dev list)" >> $CI
```

I noticed on some systems, the above command would just return blank.

If I run "nmcli dev list" straight from the CLI, I noticed that nmcli gets a segfault and thus echo puts nothing into the $CI file for that command.

While the real issue here is nmcli having a segfault, there is still valuable information in the output from "nmcli dev list" that I would like to save up until it segfaults.

Given what I have found and read on this site and Google searches, there does not seem to be too easy an answer since the command never completes due to the segfault.  But, I was hoping someone might have an idea on a workaround or other technique to capture the output up until the segfault.

```
user1@comp1:/home/user1$ nmcli dev list
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-3-ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         sky2
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.30
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:24:81:5D:F3:F9
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     not connected
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
Segmentation fault
```

results of running my script with bash -x:

```
+ echo '    <NMCLI> '
++ nmcli dev list
+ echo ''
+ echo '    </NMCLI> '
```

Entire script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define file to save configuration info to
CI=config-info.txt

# Get hostname
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
echo "    <Hostname>$HOSTNAME</Hostname>" >> $CI

# Get IP
IP=$(ifconfig | grep -m 1 -E '(inet.*Bcast.*Mask)' | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/addr:/""/)
echo "    <IP>$IP</IP>" >> $CI

# Get SubnetMask
MASK=$(ifconfig | grep -m 1 -E '(inet.*Bcast.*Mask)' | awk '{print $4}' | sed s/Mask:/""/)
echo "    <SubnetMask>$MASK</SubnetMask>" >> $CI

# Get Gateway IP
GATEWAY=$(ip route show | grep  -m 1 'default via' | awk '{print $3}')
echo "    <Gateway>$GATEWAY</Gateway>" >> $CI

# Get DNS Server IP
DNS=$(nmcli dev list | grep -m 1 DNS | awk {'print $2'})
echo "    <DNS>$DNS</DNS>" >> $CI

# Get MAC Address of NIC
MAC=$(ifconfig | grep -m 1 HWaddr | awk '{print $5}')
echo "    <MAC>$MAC</MAC>" >> $CI

# Get System Uptime
UPTIME=$(cat /proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}')
echo "    <Uptime>$UPTIME</Uptime>" >> $CI

# Get NIC linkspeed
LINKSPEED=$(nmcli dev list | grep -m 1 CAPABILITIES.SPEED | awk '{print $2 " " $3}')
echo "    <LinkSpeed>$LINKSPEED</LinkSpeed>" >> $CI

# Get NIC Vendor
# The first awk gets all columns in the line excluding the 1st column.
# The second awk removes the leading space in front of the output of the first awk
NICVENDOR=$(nmcli dev list | grep -m 1 GENERAL.VENDOR | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' |  awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")};1'
)
echo "    <NicVendor>$NICVENDOR</NicVendor>" >> $CI

# Get NIC Model
NICMODEL=$(nmcli dev list | grep -m 1 GENERAL.PRODUCT | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' |  awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")};1')
echo "    <NicModel>$NICMODEL</NicModel>" >> $CI

# Get NIC Driver Name
NICDRIVER=$(nmcli dev list | grep -m 1 GENERAL.DRIVER | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' |  awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")};1')
echo "    <NicDriver>$NICDRIVER</NicDriver>" >> $CI

# Get NIC Driver Version
NICDRIVERVERSION=$(nmcli dev list | grep -m 1 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' |  awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, "")};1')
echo "    <NicDriverVersion>$NICDRIVERVERSION</NicDriverVersion>" >> $CI

# Get "ifconfig -a" information
echo "    <Ifconfig>" >> $CI
echo "$(ifconfig -a)" >> $CI
echo "    </Ifconfig>" >> $CI

# Get "nmcli dev list" information
echo "    <NMCLI> "  >> $CI
echo "$(nmcli dev list)" >> $CI
echo "    </NMCLI> "  >> $CI

# Get "nmcli -p dev wifi list" output - This lists all detected Wireless Networks
echo "    <Wireless>" >> $CI
echo "$(nmcli -p dev wifi list)" >> $CI
echo "    </Wireless>" >> $CI

# Get "nmcli -p con status" output - Shows the status for all known network connections
echo "    <ConnectionsStatus>" >> $CI
echo "$(nmcli -p con status)" >> $CI
echo "    </ConnectionsStatus>" >> $CI

# Get "nmcli -p con list" output - Lists all connections NetworkManager has
echo "    <ConnectionsAll>" >> $CI
echo "$(nmcli -p con list)" >> $CI
echo "    </ConnectionsAll>" >> $CI

# Get "route" information
echo "    <Route>" >> $CI
echo "\"route\": " >> $CI
echo "$(route)" >> $CI
echo " " >> $CI
echo "\"route -n\": " >> $CI
echo "$(route -n)" >> $CI
echo " " >> $CI
echo "\"route -Cn\": " >> $CI
echo "$(route -Cn)" >> $CI
echo "    </Route>" >> $CI
```

Comment: you're running it in a subshell. why not just run it directly? `nmcli dev list >> foo.txt`?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.  I initially was trying to do it directly as you mentioned, but it was behaving the same way.  foo.txt was still blank.  I think I added it to a subshell in my various attempts to get it to work but I have lost track due to all the head pounding into the desk trying to get this to work  :)

Comment: @Marc B just to be sure, I re-ran directly just now, and foo.txt is blank and the CLI shows the "Segmentation fault" on the CLI.

Comment: odd. maybe that text is actually stderr output? have you tried redirecting that? `2>&1 >> foo.txt`?

Comment: @Marc B : This is odd as redirecting stderr the result is the same.  `user1@comp1:/home/user1$ nmcli dev list 2>&1 >> foo.txt
Segmentation fault
user1@comp1:/home/user1$ nmcli dev list &>> foo.txt
Segmentation fault
user1@comp1:/home/user1$ cat foo.txt
user1@comp1:/home/user1$`

Comment: @MarcB You have it in reverse order too, `2>&1 >> foo.txt` != `>> foo.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried redirecting stdout and stderr to your file.

According to documentation found at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html you can use &> to redirect both to the file or 2>&1 to redirect stderr to stdout.

```
nmcli dev list &>> $CI
```

Is all you should need. If you are running an older version of bash try the following.

```
nmcli dev list >> $CI 2>&1
```

Note: If you for some reason still want the `echo`, you need to put the redirection both in the subshell and after the command or group it and redirect the entire output like

```
echo "$(nmcli dev list >> $CI 2>&1)" >> $CI 2>&1
```

or

```
{ echo "$(nmcli dev list)"; } >> $CI 2>&1
```

Comment: This is odd as redirecting stderr the result is the same.  `user1@comp1:/home/user1$ nmcli dev list 2>&1 >> foo.txt
Segmentation fault
user1@comp1:/home/user1$ nmcli dev list &>> foo.txt
Segmentation fault
user1@comp1:/home/user1$ cat foo.txt
user1@comp1:/home/user1$`

Comment: You could try trapping the segfault. Check the first answer in [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53289/does-segmentation-fault-message-come-under-stderr) and the example the user provides in the comments.

Comment: @spetz You have the `older version` backwards, it should be `nmcli dev list >> $CI 2>&1`

Comment: @MontyP Try `nmcli dev list >> foo.txt 2>&1` . Redirection goes to where the current fd is pointing, but does not follow when it changes.

Comment: @spetz Should work for him now +1. Also edited in a part about redirecting it with the `echo`, feel free to roll it back if you don't think it adds to the answer.

Comment: @BroSlow thanks for your response.  well, I tried from the CLI `nmcli dev list >> foo.txt 2>&1` and it results in the same behavoir.  foo.txt is empty and "Segmentation fault" is printed to the terminal.  That said, if I try the 2 echo command examples you gave, the "segmentation fault" message does not appear on the terminal and foo.txt looks to have a blank newline added but no output before the segfault.  I wonder if nmcli is doing something odd behind the scene??  I did read a post where you could use script parse that output.  I've never tried that in a script before will try that too.

Comment: @MontyP Could you run `bash -x scriptname` on your script and add the output to your post? You could also try something like `nmcli dev list 2>&1 | tee foo.txt`, but not sure why that would make a difference other than printing everything to `stdout` and writing to the file.

Comment: @BroSlow I posted the output of "bash -x config-info" to my post.  I will with the tee command as well

Comment: using `nmcli dev list 2>&1 | tee foo.txt`, the "segmentation fault" message does not write to the terminal and foo.txt is empty.

Comment: @MOntyP Odd, I would actually remove or redact the `bash -x` output from your post since the output of `nmcli` gives more information than you probably want to post online.

Comment: @BroSlow  Ok.  good point  :)  I left the part where it is trying the "nmcli dev list", but as you say, doesn't show much.  See why it is driving me crazy?!? :)

Comment: @MontyP I'm confused by the behavior as well. Maybe post the entire script if possible and not sensitive.

Comment: @BroSlow  Ok.  I can do that as that is not anything sensitive.  Thanks for your efforts and suggestions.  much appreciated.